# Finding conditional expected value of a geometric distribution.

Tags: statistics

So I am given that $Y$ follows a geometric distribution.

1. Find $P[Y=2i]$ and $P[Y=2i+1]$.
2. If $Y$ is even, consider $X=\frac{Y}{2}$. What is $E[X|Y]$? If $Y$ is odd, consider $X=\frac{Y+1}{2}$. What is $E[X|Y]$?
3. Find conditional variance of $(X|y)$.

For 1, I found that $P[Y=2i]=\frac{1-p}{2-p}$ and $P[Y=2i+1]=\frac{1}{2-p}$.

For 2, I know that $E[X|Y]=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x\frac{P(X=x)}{P(Y)}$ I know that I can replace $x$ with either $\frac{2i}{2}$ (even) or $\frac{(2i+1)+1}{2}$ (odd). And I know $P(Y)$ was found. **But what is $P(X=x)$?** Is it just $P((Y=2x) or (2x-1))$? If so, $E$ would diverge?

For 3, I know that cond. variance equals $E(X^2|y)-\mu_{X|y}^2$ Once #2 is found, I will have the conditional mean squared value. And the second (conditional?) moment can be found by repetition of #2.

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: The exercise is bizarre: since $X$ is a function of $Y$, of course $E(X\mid Y)=X$ and $\mathrm{var}(X\mid Y)=0$. Sure you did not miscopy?

Comment: Hello @Did . If you're asking about whether X is a function of Y, yes, X was defined as a function of Y. I wish I had miscopied.

Comment: What is your source?

Comment: I would have thought for (1) the answers should contain $i$ while for (2) the answers were $\frac{Y}2$ and $\frac{Y+1}2$ unless you are supposed to be conditioning on $Y$ being even (or on $Y$ odd)

Comment: @Did, these are questions straight from the professor unfortunately. No source. He did mention a hint that the expected values will also follow a geometric distribution.

Comment: @Henry, I have $i$ representing the indices where $i=1,2,3,...$. Could you expand on your comment on (2)? If I am reading it correctly, yes, we are asked to find $X (X=\frac{Y}{2})$ given $Y$ is even. And again, find $X (X=\frac{Y+1}{2})$ given $Y$ is odd.

Comment: On (1) you seem to have not found $P(Y=2i)$ for a particular $i$ but $P(Y \text{ is even})$ overall.  If the three questions all have this even/odd distinction rather than looking at individual values of $Y$ then they could be clearer in saying so.

Comment: @Henry. Agreed. Professor had meant $P(Y \text{ is even})$ and $P(Y\text{ is odd})$. I apologize for the lack of clarification.